# configure serverless.yml laravel bref

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

i tried to deploy laravel serverless app with (bref) to AWS api gateway and lambda function
but i keet getting (strict-origin-when-cross-origin) with a black screen output:

```
**{"message":"Internal Server Error"}**
```

and this is my serverless.yml file

```yaml
service: laravelproject

provider:
    name: aws
    # The AWS region in which to deploy (us-east-1 is the default)
    region: eu-central-1
    # The stage of the application, e.g. dev, production, staging… ('dev' is the default)
    stage: dev
    runtime: provided.al2
  

package:
    # Directories to exclude from deployment
    patterns:
        - '!node_modules/**'
        - '!public/storage'
        - '!resources/assets/**'
        - '!storage/**'
        - '!tests/**'

functions:
    # This function runs the Laravel website/API
    web:
        handler: public/index.php
        timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-80-fpm}
        events:
            - httpApi: '*'
    # This function lets us run artisan commands in Lambda
    artisan:
        handler: artisan
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-80} # PHP
            - ${bref:layer.console} # The "console" layer

plugins:
    # We need to include the Bref plugin
    - ./vendor/bref/bref
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the php version you are specifying

Please fix ${bref:layer.php-80} as follows

```
${bref:layer.php-81}
```

I got it working with this